# How to join 3 tables and perform func.sum

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

How do I join 3 tables, Clients, Orders and Deposits and perform func.sum on Orders.total and Deposits.total for each Client.id that exists in the database ? The query result should include columns Clients.email, func.sum(Orders.total) and func.sum(Deposits.total).

So far, I've tried different queries along the lines of :

```
listeclients = db.session.query(Clients,func.sum(Clients.orders.total).\
    label("ctotal"),func.sum((Clients.deposits.total).\
    label("dtotal"))).group_by(Client.id).all()
```

giving me different errors such as:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Clients.orders has an attribute 'total'
```

I would like to see how one does this in sqlalchemy, but I'd also settle for hints behind the logic of such a query ...

Are my mappings correct? What is the syntax of such a join? Should I use eagerload somewhere? I've had success with simpler queries, but one like this is over my head for now ! Any help is welcome, even just the logic of it in raw SQL. I'm stuck w/ this ...

```
class Clients(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'clients'    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(60), index = True, unique = True)
    adresse = db.Column(db.String(64), index = True)
    telephone = db.Column(db.String(10), index = True)
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default = False)
    orders = db.relationship('Orders')
    deposits = db.relationship('Deposits') 

class Orders(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    client_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('clients.id'))
    total = db.Column(db.Float)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, index = True, default=datetime.now)    
    client = db.relationship('Clients')

class Deposits(db.Model):
    __tablename__='deposits'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, index = True, default=datetime.now)    
    client_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('clients.id'))
    total = db.Column(db.Float)  
    cheque = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    client = db.relationship('Clients')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**update:** updated the query below to handle properly the `sum`:

```
sq1 = (db.session.query(Orders.client_id, func.sum(Orders.total).label("ctotal"))
        .group_by(Orders.client_id)).subquery("sub1")

sq2 = (db.session.query(Deposits.client_id, func.sum(Deposits.total).label("dtotal"))
        .group_by(Deposits.client_id)).subquery("sub2")

q = (db.session.query(Clients, sq1.c.ctotal, sq2.c.dtotal)
    .outerjoin(sq1, sq1.c.client_id == Clients.id)
    .outerjoin(sq2, sq2.c.client_id == Clients.id)
    )
```

---

Also, instead of defining relationships twice (which might actually fail on some versions of sqlalchemy), you can simply use `backref`:

```
class Clients(db.Model):
    orders = db.relationship('Orders', backref='client')
    deposits = db.relationship('Deposits', backref='client') 

class Orders(db.Model):
    # client = db.relationship('Clients')

class Deposits(db.Model):
    # client = db.relationship('Clients')
```

Comment: Great, this query works like a charm ! kudos and I just learned a lot right there about queries and join ... on my way to writing a few more queries now ! good day

Comment: Actually, i'm just testing it some more adding data in the DB and something weird is happening in the return query: as soon as there is more that one Order or Deposit , the result of the func.sum() is multiplied by two ... is there some kind of recursivity that I am missing ? is there a "filter" that I should be adding somewhere ? How should i be tracking down this misbehaviour ? Querying by Client.id and grouping by Client.id doesn't change this behaviour ?

Comment: So this query needs to be tweaked a bit and I have not found how just yet, but here's the problem: if a client.id has one Deposit, all is fine, if he has two deposits, the value returned by the query is double of what it should be, for 3 deposits, it's triple of what it should be and so on ... i could probably trick it in the code dividing func.sum() by func.count(), but it's not pretty ! What am I missing ? Why is the number of entries in Deposits a factor in the func.sum() ?

Comment: Updated the answer which takes care of that, where original answer was a very typical mistake. Basically one needs to aggregate data separately for each table. The query then returns the whole `Clients` object, which you might want to replace with `Clients.email` if you need to have only email.

Answer (score 0):

In sql it is straightforward:

```
select c.email, sum(o.total), sum(d.total)
from Clients c
left join Orders o
    on ...
left join Deposits d
    on ...
group by c.email
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this looks very logical and simple, but i'm still trying to work it out in sqlalchemy w/o much success. I am achieving about half of what i need w/      listeclients = db.session.query(Orders,func.sum(Orders.total).label('ctotal')).group_by(Orders.client_id).all()    ... but as soon as i try to .join(Depot,func.sum(Depot.montant).label('dtotal'))  i get errors ... so i have to learn to join properly ! back to work !